Need Help with Pump Selection for Home Appliance Development
I'm currently developing a home appliance and need some your help selecting a pump, so I'm posting on this forum.
drain pumps used in washing machines from brands like Samsung and LG.
Do these kinds of pumps have self-priming capabilities? As we all know, washing machines typically allow water to flow down to the pump by gravity.
However, the machine I'm designing doesn't have water flowing down by gravity, so I need a pump that can draw water in with some suction power.
Do these types of pumps have self-priming abilities?

I doubt it because why would they?  You should ask your question with a description of your specs and you might get better responses than "no that probably won't work, you seem to have a different specification."

Pumps in washing rely on gravity as you say, so check out other pumps with sufficient suction head.
